# Is there a way to group columns with multiple conditions using pandas?

Tags: pandas

My dataframe is similar to:

```
   transaction       date  cash
0            1 2020-01-01    72
1            2 2020-01-03   100
2            2 2020-01-05   -75
3            3 2020-01-05    82
```

I want the output to group by transaction and to sum the cash for each transaction (if there is two amounts) BUT ALSO to return the later date. So for transaction 2 the end result would show transaction, date, cash as: 2,1/5/2020, 25...

Not sure how to make tables to help the visuals in my question yet so sorry, please let me know if there's any questions.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest you read this and modify your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` + `agg`. Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) examples.

```
output = df.groupby('transaction').agg({'date': 'max', 'cash': 'sum'})
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that the `date` column is encoded as proper datetime instances. If this is not currently the case, try `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` before doing the following.

```py
>>> df
   transaction       date  cash
0            1 2020-01-01    72
1            2 2020-01-03   100
2            2 2020-01-05   -75
3            3 2020-01-05    82
>>> transactions = df.groupby('transaction')
>>> pd.concat((transactions['cash'].sum(), transactions['date'].max()), axis=1)
             cash       date
transaction
1              72 2020-01-01
2              25 2020-01-05
3              82 2020-01-05
```

`transactions['date'].max()` picks the date furthest into the future of those with the same transaction ID.

Comment: I suspect there might be a more idiomatic solution involving `pivot` or `pivot_table`.